# authentication error coming while connecting to wifi by android code

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi

I am tring to connect to my WIFI by writing a simple android application.It enable the wifi.But i am getting authentication error when i see in settings of my phone for that n/w.
My code is

```
WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();

wc.SSID = "\"Network_SSID\"";
        wc.hiddenSSID = true;
        wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;     
        wc.priority = 40;
        wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN); 
        wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
        wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
        wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);

        wc.wepKeys[0] = "\"8447657855\""; //This is the WEP Password
        wc.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (Type == 1) // WIFICIPHER_NOPASS
    {
        config.hiddenSSID = true;
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    }

    if (Type == 2) // WIFICIPHER_WEP
    {
        config.hiddenSSID = true;
        config.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + Password + "\"";
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        config.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
    }

    if (Type == 3) // WIFICIPHER_WPA
    {
        config.preSharedKey = "\"" + Password + "\"";
        config.hiddenSSID = true;
    }
```